# MariaDB - insert record or update timestamp if record exists

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, sql-insert

**Objective:** cronjob runs a task; when completed successfully, insert new host record. If record exists, update timestamp to reflect this status.

```
# Table layout
> describe hosts_completed;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| timestamp | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| hostname  | varchar(32)         | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

```
# Current inventory
> select * from hosts_completed;
+----+---------------------+----------+
| id | timestamp           | hostname |
+----+---------------------+----------+
| 10 | 2020-11-02 12:51:08 | myHost1  |
| 11 | 2020-11-02 14:32:16 | MyHost2  |
+----+---------------------+----------+
```

I want to update the status for `myHost1` and my best shot would be like

```
> insert into hosts_completed(hostname) values("myHost1") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp=now();
```

and it runs but adds a new record, it does not update the `myHost1` record.

Where is the glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on duplicate key` syntax requires a unique constraint on the column that is used to detect the conflict. Create it first:

```
alter table hosts_completed 
    add constraint unique_hostname
    unique (hostname);
```

Note that this pre-requires no duplicates in the column (otherwise you need to housekeep your data before you can create the constraint).

Then you can use your curent query:

```
insert into hosts_completed(hostname) 
values('myHost1') 
on duplicate key update timestamp = now();
```